# Problema con InputMask

Tags: java, primefaces, maven

estoy tratando de utilizar la etiqueta inputMask de PrimeFaces pero no me esta funcionando, no sé que estoy haciendo mal adjunto los ejemplos de como lo estoy usando, basicamente lo estoy usando para pedirle un formato de hora:minutos (EJ: 05:35,14:10,etc) pero cuando lo pruebo me funciona igual que un inputText (sin ningun tipo de máscara, solo los números)

```
<div class="control-group">
        <div class="form-group floating-label-form-group controls">
          <label for="dateInicio">Hora inicio</label>
          <p:inputMask id="dateInicio" binding="#{superFechaInicio}" mask="99/99/9999"/> 
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="control-group">
        <div class="form-group floating-label-form-group controls">
          <label for="dateFin">Hora Fin</label>
          <p:inputMask id="dateFin" binding="#{superFechaFin}" mask="99:99"/>
        </div>
      </div>
```

Estoy usando PrimeFaces 7.0 y Mojarra 2.2.20, si conoces otra forma de hacer la validación que trato de hacer por favor ayuda! muchisimas gracias de antemano por leer

Answer (score 1):

Creo que deberías usar "value" en vez de "binding", yo así lo haría y espero te ayude.

```
<p:inputMask id="dateFin" value="#{classBean.variable}" mask="99:99"/>
```

También fijate que tengas importado los componentes de Primefaces

```
<ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">
```

Si solo quieres agregar tiempo te recomiendo el componete DatePicker

```
<p:outputLabel for="timeonly" value="Time Only:" />
<p:datePicker id="timeonly" value="#{calendarView.date14}" timeOnly="true" pattern="HH:mm"/>
```

Comment: Hola muchas gracias por contestar, me sucede lo mismo con el datePicker me queda como si fuera un inputText, creo yo que tengo bien importado los componentes ya que uso dataTable y todo en la misma página, no sé que podría ser

Comment: ¿La consola no te arroja ningún error ?